# TkinterDnd.Tk() event.data format

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop

When using TkinterDnd.Tk() to drop external files into the tk window, the event argument from the handler function has the paths of the files on a single string, separated by whitespaces.

```
def handle_drop(event):
    paths = event.data.strip()


drop_zone.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', handle_drop)
```

So by adding `.split()` to paths, I get them individually.

But my problems appear when the path itself has a whitespace on it. I can no longer split the paths.

I opened an issue on the github repo but no answer yet.

So, before you tell me to not have whitespaces on the paths, well, thats not my problem. I can't tell people how to manage their files.

So I was wondering if you guys could help me to solve this problem.

EDIT:

Example:

```
-- /path1/subfolder with spaces/file.txt
-- /path1/subfolder with spaces/video goat.avi
```

Lets say I drag these 2 files into the tkinter window.

`event.data` will contain the following

`"/path1/subfolder with spaces/file.txt /path1/subfolder with spaces/video goat.avi"`

A single string, so if I call `event.data.strip().split()` I will get something like:

`["/path1/subfolder", "with", "spaces/file.txt", "/path1/subfolder", "with", "spaces/video", "goat.avi"]`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what `event.data` looks like when you've selected two files, where at least one of them has a space in it?

Comment: I think the string returned by `event.data` for your example should be `"{/path1/subfolder with spaces/file.txt} {/path1/subfolder with spaces/video goat.avi}"` instead.

Comment: No, it is not. The string returned by event.data is a single string. And if u split it, it gets what i said. You can try yourself

Comment: Yes I have tried, but I got something like `"{...} {...}"`, i.e. filename with space inside will be surrounded by `"{}"`.

Comment: O.o which version do you have? I have tkinterdnd2 0.3.0

Comment: Okey never mind. I think it has been updated or something. Ive tried now and yep, paths are inside {}. Perhaps they did a silent update cuz i posted this error on their github few days ago

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind, paths are inside `{}` now, so gg